# How can I avoid getting extra non matching values after merging dataframes?

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, one-to-one, merging-data

I have a DataFrame with multiple columns:

```
#list
list = [('Bass', "Albert", 15), ('Bass', "Daniel", 12), ('Bass', "Paul", 31),
('Bass', "Tony", 11), ('Palmer', "Albert", 12), ('Palmer', "Daniel", 22), 
('Palmer', "Paul", 30), ('Palmer', "Tony", 50), ('Smith', "Albert", 29),
('Smith', "Daniel", 9), ('Smith', "Paul", 31), ('Smith', "Tony", 24)] 
# Create a DataFrame object 
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(list, columns =['Surname', 'Name', 'age'])
```

I would like for each `Surname` to divide the values in the `age` column by the `age` of `Paul` (i.e., for the surname Bass, divide the values by 31, then for Palmer divide them by 30, and so on ) and store these values in a new column called `age_normalized` and have these results match with the corresponding `age_initial`

```
df = df.set_index("Surname")
df2 = df.loc[df.Name =="Paul"]
```

At this point is time to divide these values and merge the dataframes

```
  results = df["age"]/df2['age']
    merge_df = df.merge(results, left_index=True, right_index=True,
 suffixes = ("_initial", "_normalized"))
```

Here is my problem: when I `print` the merge I have 4 results for each name instead of one

```
print(results.head())
Surname
Bass      0.483871
Bass      0.387097
Bass      1.000000
Bass      0.354839
Palmer    0.300000
print(df_merge.Head())
          Name  age_initial  age_normalized
Surname                                     
Bass     Albert           15        0.483871
Bass     Albert           15        0.387097
Bass     Albert           15        1.000000
Bass     Albert           15        0.354839
Bass     Daniel           12        0.483871
```

How can I merge the two dataframes and make the initial age match with the corresponding normalized age?

Comment: You haven't tagged a programming language in your question or shown us if you've made any attempt to solve this yourself.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue, I have merged `df` with `df2` first, instead of `results` and then did the division

```
df2_area = df2["age"]
mer = df.merge(df2_area, on="Surname")
mer[["age_norm"]] = mer[['age_x']].div(mer['age_y'].values, axis=0)
```